# DjangoRestFramework, how to add optional field not coming from model to serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, optional-parameters

I have a model like this:

```
class Camper(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and a viewset like this:

```
class CamperViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
...
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Retrieve a Camper instance."""
        show_weather = request.query_params.get('showWeather', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        if show_weather:
            lat = instance.location.y
            lon = instance.location.x
            instance.weather = getWeatherFromLatLon(lat, lon)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

So when I request `/api/campers/8?showWeather=true` I make another request in my view to get the weather from the current position.

How do I add it to my serializer ? It's an optional field so I need to manage this and it's only used in `/campers/id` so it will not be used in list/create/put/etc

My serializer looks like this:

```
class CamperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    camper_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')

    class Meta:
        model = Camper
        fields = ('camper_id', 'name', 'location')
```

Comment: I believe that you can just add `somefield` string to the `fields` tuple and implement method in the model named `get_somefield` and it will automatically run that method and return value to the serializer. You don't need that `SerializerMethodField`'s.

Answer (score 1):

you can add `custom serializer` for `retrive` only todo it. I called `CamperRetriveSerializer`.

Inside `CamperRetriveSerializer`, you can use `SerializerMethodField` for define field not have in database.

And you want check param `show_weather` from request, best is pass value of it to `context` and get it in serializer.

Like this:

```
    class CamperRetriveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
        weather = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
        camper_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')
    
        def get_weather(self, obj):
            show_weather = self.context.get('show_weather')
            if show_weather:
                lat = obj.location.y
                lon = obj.location.x
                return getWeatherFromLatLon(lat, lon)
    
            # define default value if not show_weather in this
            return ''
    
        class Meta:
            model = Camper
            fields = ('camper_id', 'name', 'location', 'weather')
    
    
    
    class CamperViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    
    
        def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            """Retrieve a Camper instance."""
            instance = self.get_object()
            show_weather = self.request.query_params.get('showWeather', False)
            context = {
                'show_weather': show_weather
            }
            serializer = CamperRetriveSerializer(instance, context=context)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different serializers for this.

```
class CamperViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CamperSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer_class = self.serialzier_class
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            serializer_class = CamperSerializerGet
        return serializer_class

#Serializer for GET request
class CamperSerializerGet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    weather = serialziers.SerializerMethodField()
    camper_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')

    def get_weather(self, obj):
        return obj.weather    

    class Meta:
        model = Camper
        fields = ('camper_id', 'name', 'location', 'weather')

#For other requests call this
class CamperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    camper_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id')

    class Meta:
        model = Camper
        fields = ('camper_id', 'name', 'location')
```